# I am facing issue in routing codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I am working on php Codeigniter. I am facing issue for routing.

```
 (:any)  = 'Softwareproductslist';
 (:any)/(:num)  = 'Softwareproductslist';
```

this is my dynamic software list.
Now following on that I have to set city wise list. I did as per below but it gives issues.Other routes also dying. Please help  me..

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Softwareproductslistwithcity';
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'Softwareproductslistwithcity'
```

Comment: _"I did as per below but it gives issues.Other routes also dying."_ - That's not much of an explanation what the issue actually is. What do you mean by the routes are "dying"? What actually happens? Please explain in detail.

Comment: Other pages gives 400 error due to route issue. And Images not showing on this page.But in whole project images are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

**Route:**

```
$route['cities/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'softwareproductslistwithcity/index/$1/$2';
```

**Controller for example:**

```html
class SoftwareProductsListWithCity extends MY_Controller
{
    public function index($city, $num)
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```